# How to optimize performance of searching in two array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, csv, rethinkdb

There are two array of objects one from database and one from csv. I required to compare both array object by their relative properties of Phones and emails and find duplicate array among them. Due to odd database object structure I required to compare both array with Javascript. I wanted to know what is the best algorithm and best way of compare and find duplicates?

I explain simple calculations.
There are 5000 contacts in my database and user may upload another 3000 contacts from csv. Everytime we requires to find duplicate contacts from database and if they find then it may overwrite and rest should be insert. If I compare contact row by row then it may loop **5000 database contacts x 3000 csv contacts = 15000000 time traverse**.
This is my present scenario I face due to this system goes stuck. I require some efficient solution of this issue.

I develop the stuff in NodeJS, RethinkDB.

Database object structure exactly represent like that way and it may duplicate entry of emails and phones in other contacts also.

```
[{
    id: 2349287349082734,
    name: "ABC",
    phones: [
        {
            id: 2234234,
            flag: true,
            value: 982389679823
        },
        {
            id: 65234234,
            flag: false,
            value: 2979023423
        }
    ],
    emails: [
        {
            id: 22346234,
            flag: true,
            value: "test@domain.com"
        },
        {
            id: 609834234,
            flag: false,
            value: "test2@domain.com"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Please review fiddle code, if you want: https://jsfiddle.net/dipakchavda2912/eua1truj/

I have already did indexing. The problem is looking very easy and known in first sight but when we talk about concurrency it is really very critical and CPU intensive.

Comment: So you compare csv arrays with database arrays and remove duplicates, do I understand correctly?

Comment: how do you define duplicate? please add some small data sets of the database conteacts and of the csv contact to illustrate the problem.

Comment: We did not remove but find actual index of duplicate record so later on we shall update the records

Comment: @NinaScholz I described in question that duplicate records can be defined based on emails and phones any csv contacts have phone number or emails may also find in database contacts  then it may consider as duplicates

Comment: @NinaScholz CSV has simple contacts array of object which I required to compare with database contact array of object

Comment: @NinaScholz Can you help me for this?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov I require help to get rid out of it

Comment: as i wrote, i need example(s!) of the two different styles and which item indicates a duplicate and what should happen with it. your fiddle does not help, because it is, imho, not very talkative to me.

Answer (score 0):

If understand the question you can use the **lodash** method **differenceWith**

```
let csvContacts = [] //fill it with your values;
let databaseContacts = .... //from your database
let diffArray = [] //the non duplicated object;
const l = require("lodash");
diffArray = l.differenceWith(csvContact,
                             databaseContacts,
                             (firstValue,secValue)=>firstValue.email == secValue.email
```

Comment: but what if csv and database have  multiple emails or phones and both have object format is different.

Comment: My question about optimization how could I optimize the logic and reduce execution time.